# How to determine x/y dimension lengths and dpi of a PDF image

Tags: javascript, jquery, vb.net, pdf, ocx

I need to determine the xy dimensions and DPI of a PDF image.  But I do not need to open and display the image.  Is there a utility, OCX or library in any kind of application that I can use?  If it is WEB based tools, great.  if it is desktop based like VB, VFP great.  Of course a I would like it to be freeware if possible.  If not it needs to be fast.

TIA

DK

Comment: *DPI of a PDF* - that does not make sense. A PDF can contain vector graphics, characters drawn according to font information, and embedded images. The former two are inherently without resolution, and of the latter ones there might be multiple ones of different resolutions on the same PDF page, even differently transformed.

Comment: The size of the image is defined in DPI in order to generate an image with a required resolution.  Open up PhotoShop and look at any PDF image and you will see that DPI is required to define the printing matrix.  You must be talking about a PDF document.  I am talking about a PDF Image which usually has a JPG as a base on which you can add fonts etc...

Comment: Pls see answer from 2011: http://superuser.com/questions/359839/finding-image-resolution-in-pdf-file

Answer (score 0):

Okay, no one really knows.  So I had to figure it out on my own.  Hope this helps someone else, too.

PDF files have metadata in XML form, of course.  Your program needs to be able to look for specific tags in the metadata to get the resolution and DPI.  Here is the section of that information which occurs in all PDF image files, (not necessarily all PDF files).

For the X and Y size in pixels:

```
<exif:PixelXDimension>2625</exif:PixelXDimension>
<exif:PixelYDimension>3955</exif:PixelYDimension>
```

And for the DPI:

```
<tiff:XResolution>250/1</tiff:XResolution>
<tiff:YResolution>250/1</tiff:YResolution>
<tiff:ResolutionUnit>2</tiff:ResolutionUnit>
```

This can be done easily with an in-string search, such as  ...

```
`Xpos = AT("PixelXDimension>",bPDFImage)+16`   etc...
```

...in VFoxPro.  The 16 is the length of the search string...

Regards

DK